# Roman Numeral to Integer with User Input

Tags: python

Roman numeral to integer converter with user input. I got this code below:

```
roman_numerals = {"I" : 1,
                  "V" : 5,
                  "X" : 10,
                  "L" : 50,
                  "C" : 100,
                  "D" : 500,
                  "M" : 1000
                  }

int_value = 0

user_input = input("Enter Roman Number: ").upper()

for i in range(len(user_input)):
    if user_input[i] in roman_numerals:
            if i + 1 < len(user_input) and roman_numerals[user_input[i]] < roman_numerals[user_input[i + 1]]:
                int_value -= roman_numerals[user_input[i]]
            else:
                int_value += roman_numerals[user_input[i]]
            print("The integer value is: ", int_value)
    else:
        print("Invalid input.")
```

The problem is, it prints the string "The integer value is: " the same count as the len(user_input) wherein it should only show one line of this string. For example, user inputs 'XIX' which is converted as '19' in decimal, the output goes like:

```
The integer value is: 10
The integer value is: 9
The integer value is: 19
```

I would really appreciate your feedbacks to it as I am new to python and I want to grow and improve in it.

Comment: Can you format your code properly first?  With ```  three backticks to make it readable.

Comment: well, you are printing output inside the for loop. If you don't want to print each time through the loop, then move the `print()` call outside the loop.

Comment: Don't include that `print` in the `for` loop.  `print` the final value after the `for` loop.

Comment: It does not make too much sense to break down and print *each* integer. It should be just one integer number as the final answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move your print out of the loop. Like this

```py
roman_numerals = {"I" : 1,
                  "V" : 5,
                  "X" : 10,
                  "L" : 50,
                  "C" : 100,
                  "D" : 500,
                  "M" : 1000
                  }

int_value = 0

user_input = input("Enter Roman Number: ").upper()

for i in range(len(user_input)):
    if user_input[i] in roman_numerals:
        if i + 1 < len(user_input) and roman_numerals[user_input[i]] < roman_numerals[user_input[i + 1]]:
            int_value -= roman_numerals[user_input[i]]
        else:
            int_value += roman_numerals[user_input[i]]
    else:
        print("Invalid input.")
        quit()

print("The integer value is: ", int_value)
```

Comment: Hi I tried this one as well, and it works partially since the output of this if the user inputs anything out of the dictionary, it looks like this: "Invalid input."\n "The integer value is: 0"

Comment: I added quit() function in else, so it will not print "The integer value is: 0". If I answered your question please flag it as answered. Thank you

Comment: yeah that quit() function solved my problem. I have been trying to find the correct function to it. BTW, flagged as answered. Thanks a lot

Comment: This is not quite correct. Only `I`, `X`, and `C` can be used for subtraction. Also, when subtracting, the value of the letter being subtracted from cannot be more than 10 times the value of letter being used for subtraction. Expressions like `IM` or `LD` are incorrect.